# Can't convert string into float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, integer

I'm struggling to my `df['High']` into `float`, I'm not sure what I did wrong or its any other way to convert them. Many thanks in advance.

[image]

`df.info()` details with High, Low, Volume as object type

[image]

error codes

Comment: It's because you have a `'-'` in that column. You can't convert that to a float because it's obviously not a float.

Comment: secondly. Don't post pictures of your code, post the actual code.

Comment: I run the following code to remove '-'
df['High'] = df['High'].replace('-','')[0:]

but give me the error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: sorry, first time posting here...

Comment: No worries, But put that in the original post, not the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a `'-'` in that column. Likewise, changing to just empty string of `''` will also not convert to float. You can't convert that to a float because it's obviously not a float.

You can replace the `'-'` with `nan`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'High':['20.1','100.3','99','-']})

df['High'] = df['High'].replace('-', np.nan)
df['High'] = df['High'].astype(float)
```

**Output:**

Before:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   High    4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

After:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   High    3 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that explains why! cheers for the help.